# Формирование списков с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой в лабораторной работе, никак не могу реализовать часть задания:

Даны 2 кнопки, 3 нумерованных списка с заданными классами (сlass1,class2,class3) : список первых, вторых и третьих блюд (для каждого элемента списка, где будет сформировано 3 меню из 3 блюд, находящихся в заданных списках по такому правилу (прописать заданные условия): у выбранных элементов первого списка id=id3, у второго списка - все id>2 и class!=class1, у третьего - все последние элементы из 3 первоначальных списков. По нажатию на вторую кнопку, первая кнопка должна стать некликабельной, а первые 3 списка - удалиться.

У меня получилось реализоваться только это:

> По нажатию на вторую кнопку, первая кнопка должна стать
>   некликабельной, а первые 3 списка - удалиться.

Также удалось только полностью список переносить в другой. Но никак не получилось по условию.

Как реализовать данные условия? Списки новые добавлять через .append(), это я знаю, но как их заполнить по условию?
Заранее спасибо

HTML

```
<div class="button">
    <input type="button" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="1 кнопка">
    <input type="button" id="btn2" name="btn2" value="2 кнопка">    
</div>
<div class="content">
    <ol class="class1">
        <li id="1">Борщ</li>
        <li id="2">Щи</li>
        <li id="3">Гороховый суп</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="class2">
        <li id="1">Пюре с котлетой</li>
        <li id="2">Вареная рыба</li>
        <li id="3">Омлет</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="class3">
        <li id="1">Яблочный пирог</li>
        <li id="2">Блинчик со сметаной</li>
        <li id="3">Йогурт</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Удаление списков

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    $(".class1, .class2, .class3").remove();
});
```

Добавление списка и перенос li

```
$(function ClickBtn1(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $(".content").append("<ol class="+"classNEW"+">"+"<li>Список</li>"+"</ol>");
    $(".classNEW").append($(".class1>li"));
    //alert("Я работаю!");
});
```

Comment: если что-то получилось то приводите код с версткой и опишите конкретную проблему что не получается. пока что мы тут видим только целое учебное задание, которые тут не приветствуются без самостоятельного решения.

Comment: Для ответа на ваш вопрос, нужен код. Покажите, что сделали, что пытались сделать и не получилось.

Comment: Добавил свой пример кода

Comment: У Вас id в коде повторяются - это недопустимо по правилам w3c. id на странице должен быть уникальным. И совсем непонятно, что же именно должно происходить (что значит "id=id3", "все id>2" и "class!=class1" ?) Вы можете чётко по пунктам описать алгоритм - что на каком шаге происходит?

Comment: Первый список состоит из элементов имеющих id = 3, второй список содержит в себе все элементы списков в которых id > 2, в третьем списке я сам не понял что должно происходить. Списки которые будут формироваться, должны заново создаваться, как я вот и написал, через .append()

Comment: Насчет уникальности id я знаю, но это требует задание, увы, ничего с этим не могу поделать

Comment: @DvogR, так id > 2 - это тоже самое, что id = 3 (потому что больше 2 в этих списках только 3). Вы уверены, что Вы правильно поняли задание и правильно его приводите? Есть где-то первоисточник?

Comment: я дословно сюда написал условие задания (слово в слово из первоисточника(это pdf файл) специально) я сам не совсем понимаю само задание, поэтому прошу вас помочь понять)

Comment: Или вы неправильно поняли задание, или идите возмущаться к преподавателю и материть его, ибо чего это он даёт заведомо некорректные задания с неуникальными id

Comment: Боюсь я тогда ничего не сдам) Но все равно спасибо что посмотрели